# two minipages next to each other: the right is shifted vertically

Tags: minipage

Hy,first post here. Hope I will do well.
I have a problem with setting up two minipages next to each other. The right one is always shifted vertically downwards. Here is my example code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
% --- Language Settings: ------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{bbm, amssymb, amsmath, amsfonts}%fonttypes, mathtypes, etc.
\usepackage[german,ngerman,english]{babel}  %English and German for fancyref


% --- Textformat: -------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}            %use of utf8x code
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                %Paket for umlauts
\usepackage{ulem}                       %Paket for underline text
\usepackage{enumitem}                   %Paket for enumerations
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}    %for singlepspacecing
\usepackage{framed}                     %draws a frame around the text

\begin{document}

\hrule
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{singlespace}
        \begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*}.]
                \item Questionnaire Number/ID: \dots
                \item Name of Community: \dots
                \item Date of Interview: \dots / 09 / 2014
                \item Time Interview started: \dots
                \item Enumerator´s Name: \dots
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{singlespace}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{singlespace}
        \begin{enumerate}[label=]
                \item
                \item Community Code/ID: \dots
                \item
                \item Time Interview ended: \dots
                \item Enumerator Code/ID: \dots
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{singlespace}
\end{minipage}
\medskip
\hrule
\smallskip

\end{document}
```

I tried to use \nointend and I tried to deleted all unnecessary empty spaces. I want to have both minipages next to each other so that the lines "Nome of Community" and "Community Code/ID" are in the same line.

Background: It´s a questionnaire and the lines should be "in line" to look good.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Nice minimal example!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to align entries, use a `tabular`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  r@{ }l
  @{\extracolsep{\stretch{2}}}
  l
  @{\extracolsep{\stretch{1}}}
  l@{}
}
\toprule
a. & Questionnaire Number/ID: \dots       &&\\
b. & Name of Community: \dots             & Community Code/ID: \dots & \\
c. & Date of Interview: \dots / 09 / 2014 &&\\
d. & Time Interview started: \dots        & Time Interview ended: \dots & \\
e. & Enumerator´s Name: \dots             & Enumerator Code/ID: \dots & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Play with the arguments in `\stretch`; here the space between the second and third columns is twice than the space between the third column and the mock fourth.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add few `\strut`s:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
% --- Language Settings: ------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{bbm, amssymb, amsmath, amsfonts}%fonttypes, mathtypes, etc.
\usepackage[german,ngerman,english]{babel}  %English and German for fancyref


% --- Textformat: -------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}            %use of utf8x code
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                %Paket for umlauts
\usepackage{ulem}                       %Paket for underline text
\usepackage{enumitem}                   %Paket for enumerations
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}    %for singlepspacecing
\usepackage{framed}                     %draws a frame around the text
\begin{document}
\noindent
\hrule
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{singlespace}
        \begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*}.]
                \item \strut Questionnaire Number/ID: \dots
                \item Name of Community: \dots
                \item \strut Date of Interview:                            ... / 09 / 2014
                \item Time Interview started: \dots
                \item Enumerator´s Name: \dots
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{singlespace}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{singlespace}
        \begin{enumerate}[label={}]
                \item \strut
                \item Community Code/ID: \dots
                \item \strut
                \item Time Interview ended: \dots
                \item Enumerator Code/ID: \dots
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{singlespace}
\end{minipage}
\medskip
\hrule
\smallskip

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may like to add `leftmargin=*,nosep` to the options of `enumerate` in both `minipage`s.

Comment: if you look at this more carefully, only one `\strut` is needed: in the first item of the second box.  the third item in that box will take care of itself, and the first item in the first box already has both caps and descenders.